# Convert resource routes in Rails to non-resource routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have implemented this simple form using non-db backed models. And I'm able to perform validations and showing form fields on it. But I have implemented this using resource. Now I want to learn about how to add more actions, apart from CRUD into this, and defining routes for them. Or if I want to stop using `resources`, and explicitly define paths for actions. How should I proceed with this?

My files:

**Controller : new_forms_controller.rb**

```
class NewFormsController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @form = NewForm.new
   flash[:notice] = nil
  end

  def index

  end

  def create
    @form = NewForm.new(params[:new_form])
    if @form.valid?
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created recommendation."
      render :action => 'show'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def show

  end

end
```

**Model : new_form.rb**

```
class NewForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :title, :article, :content, :author

  validates :title, :article, :content, :author, :presence => true
  validates :title, :article => {:minimum => 5 }

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

**Routes : route.rb**

```
TestBranch::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :new_forms
  root :to => "new_forms#new"
end
```

**New View**

```
<%= content_for :title, "New Form" %>

<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <p><%= flash[:notice]%></p>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @form do |f| %>

    <% if @form.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2>
            <%= pluralize(@form.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
            this article from being saved:
          </h2>
          <ul>
            <% @form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :titleID %> <br/>
      <%= f.text_field :titleID %><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :articleID %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :articleID %><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :content %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :content %><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :author %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :author %><br/>
    </p>

    <p><%= f.submit "Submit"  %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resources` basically saves you writing a lot of code and gives you ability to write the code yourself. Since, you have asked to explicitly define paths on your own, you can define them in following way:

In routes.rb,

```
get '/users' => 'users#index'
get '/users/:id' => 'users#show'
get '/users/new' => 'users#new'
post '/users' => 'users#create'
get '/users/:id/edit' => 'users#edit'
put '/users' => 'users#update'
delete '/users' => 'users#destroy'
```

These all lines are basically equivalent to `resources :users`. And additionally, you have asked about how to add more actions, and to define accordingly routes for them: first, you can take a look at what I wrote for `resources :users`, and second, you can take a look at [guides for routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: So if I add above routes, and remove resources :new_forms from routes.tb, my application should work fine? But it's showing     undefined method `new_forms_path'  error in line 7 : <%= form_for @form do |f| %>

Comment: Did you add the exact same routes? You should define them for `form`, like `get '/forms' => 'forms#index'`.

Comment: Oh! My bad! I just blindly copied above code! I changed it to new_forms, and it is working fine now. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome! If this answers your question, you can accept it. By clicking on the 'tick' mark on left side in screen, you can accept an answer.

Comment: Hey, So I added a action organise under reports controller! In the routes.rb , I added : `resources :reports do collection do get 'organise' end end` and I'm using `organise_reports_path` to link to this location. But I'm getting `undefined local variable or method `organise_reports_path' ` error.

Answer (score 1):

Adding extra routes to resources is pretty simple:
Customizing the routes generated by `resources` is quite easy:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :search
  end

  member do
    get :info
  end
end
```

This would give us:

```
GET /users/search => users#search
GET /users/:id/info => users#info
```

However before adding any more routes ask yourself if what you are trying to achieve does not actually match one of the existing CRUD actions - in nine times out of ten it does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add required actions to you controller and add corresponding routes to `route.rb`. Here is an example:

In `route.rb`:

```
TestBranch::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :new_forms do
    collection do
      get :new_action1    # will produce /new_forms/new_action1
      post :new_action2   # will produce /new_forms/new_action2
      delete :new_action3 # will produce /new_forms/new_action3
    end

    member do
      get :new_action4    # will produce /new_forms/:id/new_action4
      put :new_action5    # will produce /new_forms/:id/new_action5
      delete :new_action6 # will produce /new_forms/:id/new_action6
    end
  end

  root :to => "new_forms#new"
end
```

Controller: `new_forms_controller.rb`

```
class NewFormsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new_action1
    ...
  end

  def new_action2
    ...
  end

  def new_action3
    ...
  end

  def new_action4
    ...
  end

  def new_action5
    ...
  end

  def new_action6
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define routes manualy using the `match`

```
match 'new_form' => 'new_form#index', :via => :get
```

This will match a `get` request to `/new_form` to the `index` action in `new_form` controller